# Show/Hide Comments in Excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, comments

I have comments on an Excel spreadsheet.

I have one button to control whether the comments are displayed or hidden. When a user clicks the button, the comments should show. When the user clicks it again, the comments should go away.

Below is the code I'm trying to use - they both work independently, but when I put in an If Then Else statement, I get errors:

```
Sub showcomments()

If Comments <> "Visible" Then Application.DisplayCommentIndicator = xlCommentAndIndicator
Else: Application.DisplayCommentIndicator = xlCommentIndicatorOnly
End If
    
End Sub
```

I tried `else if comments = visible`.

I usually get the error "else without if".

Comment: It's for a dashboard I created so I'm trying to make it as simple and clean as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
   Sub showcomments()
   Comments = 1
   For Each MyComments In ActiveSheet.Comments
       If MyComments.Visible = True Then
           Comments = 0
       End If
   Next
   If Comments = 1 Then
       Application.DisplayCommentIndicator = xlCommentAndIndicator
   Else
       Application.DisplayCommentIndicator = xlCommentIndicatorOnly
   End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Was wanting to do this in Excel myself. If I'm not mistaken, this works perfectly fine for what you want and requires no looping or extra global variables...

```
Sub showcomments()
  If Application.DisplayCommentIndicator = xlCommentIndicatorOnly Then
    Application.DisplayCommentIndicator = xlCommentAndIndicator
  Else
    Application.DisplayCommentIndicator = xlCommentIndicatorOnly
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: ..this works perfect for me on Win10/MS Office 2010! Thx!

Answer (score 0):

This method uses a global variable and doesn't have to loop through all your comments.

```
Public comments As Integer

Sub showcomments()
 If comments = 1 Then
   Application.DisplayCommentIndicator = xlCommentAndIndicator
   comments = 0
  Else
    Application.DisplayCommentIndicator = xlCommentIndicatorOnly
    comments = 1
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This one works too, thanks!  Gonna try and compare the two that worked with mine and figure out what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I used another approach which I find easier:

```
Sub Show_Hide_Comments(visible As Boolean)
  Dim cmnt As Comment
   For Each cmnt In ActiveSheet.comments
       cmnt.Shape.Visible = visible
   Next
End Sub
```

This finds all comments and hides their shape.
You can even do this individually for certain comments if you wish.