# How to Show/Hide all comments on an Excel sheet (but not impact other sheets)

Tags: excel, comments, show-hide

I want to have a button Show/hide all comments on the active Excel sheet only.  I implemented and am fairly happy with this solution (using Application.DisplayCommentIndicator): 
[Simple VBA Show/Hide Excel Comments problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19014723/simple-vba-show-hide-excel-comments-problems)
The only issue is that this solution shows/hides comments on every sheet open in the application. I need it to only operate on the active sheet (IE. the one with the button) This is especially inconvenient because the other sheets (in other workbooks) don't have the Show/Hide button.

Comment: Do you want to show the comments, as if you're hovering over the cell? Or do you want to put the comments in a cell?  Also, the solution that you linked to, runs on ALL sheets? Not just the active one?

Answer (score 0):

I have a semi-fix for your issue. Let's say if the user pressed your button to hide the comments, which is located in `Sheet1`, but then decides to switch to another worksheet, all comments would be activated again.

Problem: if the user switches back to `Sheet1`, the comments will be hidden and the user would have to press unhide regardless of their previous selection if they would like to see the comments:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)

    If Sh.Name = "Sheet1" Then
    Application.DisplayCommentIndicator = xlCommentIndicatorOnly
    Else
    Application.DisplayCommentIndicator = xlCommentAndIndicator
    End If

End Sub
```